# complete spaces and the baire principle

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

There is this problem that I can't get an answer to.

Begin with $(X,p)$ a complete metric space, with no isolated points. 
(This means that every point is an accumulation point, right?) 
Now prove that for every sequence $(O_n)$ of open, dense subsets of X and every countable set $L$,  $$L\cap (\cap_n O_n)\neq \emptyset$$

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's true.  Let $O_n=\Bbb R \setminus \{n\}$, for each $n\in\Bbb N$.
Let $L=\Bbb N$.

Then $\cap O_n=\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb N$.

So $L\cap(\cap O_n)=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 3):

Not only is it false, but it’s false in a very strong way: if $L$ is *any* countable subset of $X$, there is a family $\{U_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ of dense open sets in $X$ such that $L\cap\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}U_n=\varnothing$. (Perhaps this result is what the problem was supposed to be.)

The proof is easy: index $L=\{x_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$, and for each $n\in\Bbb N$ let $U_n=X\setminus\{x_n\}$. Since $X$ has no isolated points, each $U_n$ is open and dense, and clearly $L\cap\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}U_n=\varnothing$.

Comment: It's false for the reals R even if we let L have the cardinal of the reals because R has  dense $G_{\delta}$ subsets whose complements have the same cardinal as R.

Comment: @user254665: Of course, but that seemed too far removed from the version in the question to be worth mentioning unless the OP returns and revises the question.